# XML in Java, how to show an @XmlElement Atribute Java Bean Null as a Empty Valuein XML (Solution Found)

Tags: java, xml, xml-literals

im working in a project. A have a Java Bean with some properties. I mark each attribute with the Tag @XmlElement, like this:

```
@XmlElement(name="id", nillable = true)
private String test;
```

I put this "nillable", it shows me the tag, even when is null true but it shows me a message in xml when is null

```
<id xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

But when it's null i want to show a empty value with the tags only, like this

```
<id></id>
```

And i don't know how to do this. I searched but i didn't found how, thats why i'm asking.

And more 1 Thing, can i generate XML that's with no attributes ? Because im My XML i have to generate aloot blank tags, with nothing inside, just the tags and i dont wanna make aloot of atributes if i wont use this just to show the Tag

Thanks !

The imports and some config that i using

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="test")
```

---------Solution----------

Hi, guys, i found a solution.
I Want to share if someone got stuck in same problem.
Ou declare the property of the Class as empty, something like
String personName = "";

Them you don't need to create the Getters and Setters if you wont change this value and just want the tag appers in XML but empty.

Note: For this work you have to use the 
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) in your class.
Thanks to all.
Bye

Comment: Did you try to add the 'required = true' in '@XmlElement' annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to represent a `null` value in XML.

**One option** is the described `xsi:nil`. It just adds an empty tag for your attribute and *annotates it* as holding null value. This form is generated by [JAXB](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) if you annotate your attributes with `nillable = true`.

Note that en empty tag is not the same as a tag with empty string - but more on that later.

**Another option** is not to represent that attribute at all. There will just be no tag for the attribute in the XML. [JAXB](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) uses this approach by default if you don't annotate your Java code with `nillable = true` but the attributes will still have `null` values.

And that's it.

Now, to what you want to achieve. Rendering `<id></id>` basically means that you have an `id` attribute that holds an **empty string**. Although you could probably find a language when this is equivalent to `null` value (Oracle's PL/SQL for instance), it's obviously not an equivalent of `null` value in Java.

Moreover, if the `id` is modeled as `long` or `int` (or any non-String type) in your Java Bean, the parser will fail to de-serialize such XML back into the bean instance.